# Vue.js - click events and "this"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a todo list in vue and I'm using `pop()` to clear out/delete list items. See the code in question below:

```js
// components
Vue.component('todoitem', {
  template: "<li>Test Item</li>"
})

// app code
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: 'Sample Item 1' },
      { text: 'Sample Item 2' },
      { text: 'Sample Item 3' }
    ],
    button: {
      text: 'Hide'
    },
    seen: true
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      let item = document.getElementById("list-input").value;
      let error = document.getElementById("error");
      if (item == "") {
        error.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        app.todos.push({ text: item });
        error.style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    removeItem: function() {
     this.todos.pop();
    },
    toggleSeen: function() {
      app.seen = !app.seen;
      app.button.text = app.seen ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.todo-list {
  list-style-type: square;
}

.todo-list__delete {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .todo-list__delete {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
      <a v-on:click="removeItem" class="todo-list__delete" href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="text" id="list-input">
  <input type="submit" id="list-submit" v-on:click="addItem">
  <span id="error" style="color: red; display: none;">Please Enter Text</span>

  <ul>
    <todoitem></todoitem>
  </ul>

  <h2 v-if="seen">SEEN</h2>
  <button id="hide-seen" v-on:click="toggleSeen">{{ button.text }}</button>
</div>
```

The expected behavior is that when delete is clicked, it invokes the removeItem function and with the usage of `this` in that function it deletes the selected item. However what actually happens is it just deletes nodes starting from the bottom.

I *thought* the issue is that with `this` I'm actually referencing the delete link and not actually the `<li>` element I'm trying to remove. So I tried both:

```
removeItem: function() {
    this.todos.parentElement.pop();
}
```

And:

```
removeItem: function() {
    this.parentElement.todos.pop();
}
```

With no luck.

How does `this` work in Vue?

Comment: You might want to review what the `pop` function actually does. I think you will find the explanation for your behavior. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Comment: Ok. I was just looking for the opposite of `push()` but that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context, `this` refers to the Vue component (not the DOM element).  `this.todos` is the `todos` array inside the component's `data` object, and  `pop` removes the last item of an array.  So that's why the last element is being removed.

If you want to remove a specific element you'll need to pass some information to the `removeItem` function about which element you want removed and then have `removeItem()` drop that specific element from the `todos` array instead of `pop`ping the last element.  One simple way to do this would be to pass the array index to the `removeItem` function, and then `splice` that index out of the todos array:

```
<li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
  ...
  <a v-on:click="removeItem(index)">Delete</a>
</li>
```

```
removeItem: function(index) {
  this.todos.splice(index, 1);
},
```

Your full snippet with that change applied is below:

```js
// components
Vue.component('todoitem', {
  template: "<li>Test Item</li>"
})

// app code
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: 'Sample Item 1' },
      { text: 'Sample Item 2' },
      { text: 'Sample Item 3' }
    ],
    button: {
      text: 'Hide'
    },
    seen: true
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
      let item = document.getElementById("list-input").value;
      let error = document.getElementById("error");
      if (item == "") {
        error.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        app.todos.push({ text: item });
        error.style.display = "none";
      }
    },
    removeItem: function(index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    },
    toggleSeen: function() {
      app.seen = !app.seen;
      app.button.text = app.seen ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.todo-list {
  list-style-type: square;
}

.todo-list__delete {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .todo-list__delete {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li v-for="(todo, index) in todos">
      {{ todo.text }}
      <a v-on:click="removeItem(index)" class="todo-list__delete" href="#">Delete</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="text" id="list-input">
  <input type="submit" id="list-submit" v-on:click="addItem">
  <span id="error" style="color: red; display: none;">Please Enter Text</span>

  <ul>
    <todoitem></todoitem>
  </ul>

  <h2 v-if="seen">SEEN</h2>
  <button id="hide-seen" v-on:click="toggleSeen">{{ button.text }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: My original method for choosing which item to delete was problematic (it'd delete all items with the same text.)  I changed it to use the array index instead.